# Should I take ILogger, ILogger<T>, ILoggerFactory or ILoggerProvider for a library?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core, .net-standard

This may be somewhat related to [Pass ILogger or ILoggerFactory to constructors in AspNet Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46013762/91), however this is specifically about **Library Design**, not about how the actual application that uses those libraries implement its logging.

I am writing a .net Standard 2.0 Library that will be installed via Nuget, and to allow people using that Library to get some debug info, I'm depending on [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/) to allow a standardized Logger to be injected.

However, I'm seeing multiple interfaces, and sample code on the web sometimes uses `ILoggerFactory` and creates a logger in the ctor of the class. There's also `ILoggerProvider` which looks like a read-only version of the Factory, but implementations may or may not implement both interfaces, so I'd have to pick. (Factory seems more common than Provider).

Some code I've seen uses the non-generic `ILogger` interface and might even share one instance of the same logger, and some take an `ILogger<T>` in their ctor and expect the DI container to support open generic types or explicit registration of each and every `ILogger<T>` variation my library uses.

Right now, I do think that `ILogger<T>` is the right approach, and maybe a ctor that doesn't take that argument and just passes a Null Logger instead. That way, if no logging is needed, none is used. However, some DI containers pick the largest ctor and thus would fail anyway.

I'm curious of what I'm *supposed* to be doing here to create the least amount of headache for users, while still allowing proper logging support if desired.

Comment: It seems like Microsoft injects `ILoggerFactory` for [Library design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs)... however as I explained below I don't think injecting a factory is a good solution.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini have you never coded with  strategy pattern and abstract factory is a DI solution?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

### Definition

We have 3 interfaces: `ILogger`, `ILoggerProvider` and `ILoggerFactory`. Let's look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions) to find out their responsibilities:

**ILogger**: is responsible for writing a log message of a given *Log Level*.

**ILoggerProvider**: is responsible for creating an instance of `ILogger` (you are not supposed to use `ILoggerProvider` directly to create a logger)

**ILoggerFactory**: you can register one or more `ILoggerProvider`s with the factory, which in turn uses all of them to create an instance of `ILogger`. `ILoggerFactory` holds a collection of `ILoggerProviders`.

In the example below, we are registering 2 providers (console and file) with the factory. When we create a logger, the factory uses both of these providers to create an instance of `Logger`:

```
ILoggerFactory factory = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole();    // add console provider
factory.AddProvider(new LoggerFileProvider("c:\\log.txt"));   // add file provider
Logger logger = factory.CreateLogger(); // creates a console logger and a file logger
```

So the logger itself maintains a collection of `ILogger`s, and it writes the log message to all of them. [Looking at Logger source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/Logger.cs) we can confirm that `Logger` has an array of `ILoggers` (i.e. `LoggerInformation[]`), and at the same time it is implementing `ILogger` interface.

---

### Dependency Injection

[MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) provides 2 methods for injecting a logger:

> **1. Injecting the factory:**
>
> ```
> public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoRepository, ILoggerFactory logger)
> {
>     _todoRepository = todoRepository;
>     _logger = logger.CreateLogger("TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController");
> }
> ```

*creates a Logger with Category = TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController*.

> **2. Injecting a generic `ILogger<T>`:**
>
> ```
> public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoRepository, ILogger<TodoController> logger)
> {
>     _todoRepository = todoRepository;
>     _logger = logger;
> }
> ```

*creates a logger with Category = fully qualified type name of TodoController*

---

In my opinion, what makes the documentation confusing is that it does not mention anything about injecting a non-generic, `ILogger`. In the same example above, we are injecting a non-generic `ITodoRepository` and yet, it does not explain why we are not doing the same for `ILogger`.

According to [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/):

> An Injection Constructor should do no more than receiving the
> dependencies.

Injecting a factory into the Controller is not a good approach, because it is not Controller's responsibility to initialize the Logger (violation of SRP). At the same time injecting a generic `ILogger<T>` adds unnecessary noise. See *Simple Injector's* blog for more details: [What’s wrong with the ASP.NET Core DI abstraction?](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/)

What should be injected (at least according to the article above) is a non-generic `ILogger`, but then, that's not something that Microsoft's Built-in DI Container can do, and you need to use a 3rd party DI Library. [These](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/30/third-party-dependency-injection-asp-net-core/) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788637/continued-ninject-support-in-asp-net-mvc-6/32797105#32797105) documents explain how you can use 3rd party libraries with .NET Core.

---

This is [another article](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection/) by Nikola Malovic, in which he explains his 5 laws of IoC.

> **Nikola’s 4th law of IoC**
>
> Every constructor of a class being resolved should not have any
> implementation other than accepting a set of its own dependencies.

Comment: Your answer and Steven's article are most correct and most depressing at the same time.

Comment: If ``AddConsole`` is not found, make sure that NuGet "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" is installed, your source file includes `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;`. Then finally try `ILoggerFactory factory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());`

Comment: If `LoggerFileProvider` is not found, use `FileLoggerProvider` from NuGet "NReco.Logging.File".

Comment: Sorry which article and specifically what part of text are you claiming explains why ILogger<T> being injected is a bad thing? I agree about not injecting a factory in general but why is ILogger<T> worse than ILogger? T is typically the consuming class that is taking the dependency

Comment: Quoting Steven's comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843110/ninject-how-inject-a-generic-loggert-by-calling-loggerfactory-createlogger): "Injection of a `ILogger<T>` is just noise to the consumer that can lead to accidental errors when a wrong T is specified and it complicates testing."... "Injecting `ILoggerFactory` and `ILogger<T>` is a terrible idea, and as I see it, the only reason Microsoft is doing this (and promoting it publicly) is because their built-in container lacks the possibility to map a non-generic interface to a generic implementation."

Comment: If you have a non generic ILogger, then you can only log in that category in your library can't you? isn't the point of taking ILogger<T> or ILoggerFactory that both allow you to log in a category specific to your library, so that collecting those logs could be excluded from collecting the logs of the application. If you just pass ILogger it'll all log in the same place won't it?

Comment: @SamHolder: you want your non generic logger to know the category... so you want your DI container to map a non-generic interface to a generic implementation.

Comment: I liked the article but I have a key question that I cannot seem to resolve. I created my own ILoggerProvider to provide for a specific implementation of using a sproc to log to SQL Server in our environment. In what part of the DI chain can I call AddProvider on the ILoggerFactory in order to ensure that every ILogger the factory produces has the ILoggerProvider implementation added to it?

Comment: It's worth noting that the pattern you are describing (an implementation of ILogger which is itself an aggregation of ILogger instances, calling each one "under the hood") is a [decorator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator).  Good software design patterns should be promoted.

Answer (score 41):

Those are all valid except for `ILoggerProvider`. `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>` are what you're supposed to use for logging. To get an `ILogger`, you use an `ILoggerFactory`. `ILogger<T>` is a shortcut to get a logger for a particular category (shortcut for the type as the category).

When you use the `ILogger` to perform logging, each registered `ILoggerProvider` gets a chance to handle that log message. It's not really valid for consuming code to call into the `ILoggerProvider` directly.

Comment: Thanks. This makes me think that an `ILoggerFactory` would be great as an easy way to wire up DI for consumers by only having 1 dependency (*"Just give me a Factory and I'll create my own loggers"*), but would prevent using an existing logger (unless the consumer uses some wrapper). Taking an `ILogger` - generic or not - allows the consumer to give me a logger they specially prepared, but makes the DI setup potentially a lot more complex (unless a DI container that supports Open Generics is used). Does that sound correct? In that case, I think I'll go with the factory.

Comment: @MichaelStum - I'm not sure I follow your logic here. You're expecting your consumers to use a DI system but then are wanting to take over and manually manage dependencies within your library? Why would that seem the right approach?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is a good point. Taking a factory seems odd. I think that instead of taking an `ILogger<T>`, I'll take an `ILogger<MyClass>` or even just `ILogger` instead - that way, the user can wire it up with only a single registration, and without requiring open generics in their DI container. Leaning towards the non-generic `ILogger`, but will experiment a lot over the weekend.

Answer (score 20):

## When writing a library, `ILoggerFactory` or `ILoggerFactory<T>` is the way to go.

### Why?

#### As a library author, you may care about:

- The content of a message
- The severity of a message
- The category/class/grouping of a message

#### You may not care about:

- Which logging library a consumer uses
- Whether a logging library is provided at all

### When I write libraries:

I write classes in such a way that I control the content and severity of messages (and sometimes the category) while allowing the consumer to choose whatever logging implementation they desire or none at all if they so choose.

### Examples

#### Non-generic class

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;

public class MyClass
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;

  public MyClass(
    ..., /* required deps */
    ..., /* other optional deps */
    ILoggerFactory? loggerFactory)
  {
    _logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger<MyClass>()
      ?? NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger<MyClass>();
  }
}
```

#### Generic class

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;

public class MyClass<T>
{
  private readonly ILogger<T> _logger;

  public MyClass<T>(
    ..., /* required deps */
    ..., /* other optional deps */
    ILoggerFactory? loggerFactory)
  {
    _logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger<T>()
      ?? NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger<T>();
  }
}
```

### Now you can:

- Use the full MS ILogger interface to do all your logging, not caring if there really is a logger at all
- Substitute the generic `CreateLogger<T>()` for the non-generic `CreateLogger("")` if you need to control the category.

### For the grumbles:

- Yes, you could use `ILogger`, or `ILogger<T>` in the constructor if you don't care about the category, but I'm proposing this as the most universal/generic way, that gives you the most options without stepping on the consumer.
- The consumer can still override the category with the configuration of the log factory or their logger implementation.
- You're not necessarily initializing anything by accepting a log factory, It's up to the DI container configuration/consumer
- The null logger doesn't count as overhead in my book since we're using a single instance
- The consumer can pass in a NullLoggerFactory, if they want to
- And if you're really overkill, you can have a library configuration setting that (with a modification to the constructor) will enable/disable logging for the library (conditionally force the NullLogger)

Comment: I completly doesn't understand a word about those injections things, but with you explanation it works !
Thank you very much.

Comment: One big advantage I see with using ILoggerFactory is, that if you use AnotherLib (that may accept ILogger or ILoggerFactory) within MyLib, you can create a new logger with a dedicated category for AnotherLib. It would be confusing to have log entries from AnotherLib logged in the category "MyLib".

Answer (score 15):

The `ILogger<T>` was the actual one that is made for DI. The `ILogger<T>` came in order to help implement the factory pattern much more easily, instead of you writing on your own all the DI and Factory logic, that was one of the smartest decisions in ASP.NET Core

You can choose between:

`ILogger<T>` if you have a need to use factory and DI patterns in your code **or** you could use the `ILogger`, to implement simple logging with no DI needed.

Given that, the `ILoggerProvider` is just a bridge to handle each of the registered log's messages. There is no need to use it, as it does not effect anything that you should intervene in code. It listens to the registered `ILoggerProvider` and handles the messages. That's about it.

Comment: What does ILogger vs ILogger<T> have to do with DI? Either would be injected, no?

Comment: It's actually ILogger<TCategoryName> in MS Docs. It derives from ILogger and adds no new functionality except the class name to log. This also provides a unique type so the DI injects the correctly named logger. Microsoft extensions extend the non-generic `this ILogger`.

Answer (score 10):

Sticking to the question, I believe `ILogger<T>` is the right option, considering downside of other options:

1. Injecting `ILoggerFactory` force your user to give away the control of the mutable global logger factory to your class library. Moreover, by accepting `ILoggerFactory` your class now can write to log with any arbitrary category name with `CreateLogger` method. While `ILoggerFactory` is usually available as a singleton in DI container, I as a user would doubt why any library would need to use it.
2. While the method `ILoggerProvider.CreateLogger` looks like it, it is not intended for injection. It is used with `ILoggerFactory.AddProvider` so the factory can create aggregated `ILogger` that writes to multiple `ILogger` created from each registered providers. This is clear when you inspect [the implementation of `LoggerFactory.CreateLogger`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggerFactory.cs#L63)
3. Accepting `ILogger` also looks like the way to go, but it is impossible with .NET Core DI. This actually sounds like the reason why they needed to provide `ILogger<T>` at the first place.

So after all, we have no better choice than `ILogger<T>`, if we were to choose from those classes.

Another approach would be to inject something else that wraps non-generic `ILogger`, which in this case should be non-generic one. The idea is that by wrapping it with your own class, you take full control of how user could configure it.

Comment: Why is `ILogger` impossible? We accidentally tried this out by registering a singleton instance in the services and and found that in the constructor, an `ILogger` was provided by DI, but it wasn't logging.

Answer (score 9):

For library design, good approach would be:

1. Do not force consumers to inject logger to your classes. Simply create another constructor passing NullLoggerFactory.

   ```cs
   class MyClass
   {
       private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

       public MyClass():this(NullLoggerFactory.Instance)
       {

       }
       public MyClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
       {
         this._loggerFactory = loggerFactory ?? NullLoggerFactory.Instance;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Limit number of categories which you use when you create loggers to allow consumers configure logs filtering easily.

   ```cs
   this._loggerFactory.CreateLogger(Consts.CategoryName)
   ```

Answer (score 8):

The default approach is meant to be `ILogger<T>`. This means that in the log the logs from the specific class will be clearly visible because they will include the full class name as the context. For example if the full name of your class is `MyLibrary.MyClass` you will get this in the log entries created by this class. For example:

> MyLibrary.MyClass:Information: My information log

You should use the `ILoggerFactory` if you want to specify your own context. For example that all the logs from your library have the same log context instead every class. For example:

```
loggerFactory.CreateLogger("MyLibrary");
```

And then the log will look like this:

> MyLibrary:Information: My information log

If you do that in all classes then the context will be just MyLibrary for all classes. I imagine you would want to do that for a library if you don't want to expose the inner class structure in the logs.

Regarding the optional logging. I think you should always require the ILogger or ILoggerFactory in the constructor and leave it to the consumer of the library to turn it off or provide a Logger that does nothing in the dependency injection if they don't want logging. It is very easy to turn of the logging for a specific context in the configuration. For example:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "MyLibrary": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer to keep it simple and inject the non generic ILogger

This seems to be non-default behavior - but is easily wired up with the following:

```
services.AddTransient(s => s.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(""));
```

Comment: Why giving this advice? Logging to the "default" logger just disables all configuration and filtering you can do on categories.

Comment: Because maybe someone doesn't care about features like that. Spent 13 years without filtering on categories. Also, more advanced DI containers have the ability to resolve `ILogger` in a context-aware way to get an `ILogger<[Class-Where-I'm-Injected]>` at runtime, which I'd prefer most of the times over this not too nice "self-generic" bolierplate. Of course this is just my opinion.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási But that is exactly what you get with `ILogger<Class-Where-I'm-Injected>`.

Comment: Because I prefer to keep it simple.  
Simple is ILogger and not worrying about categories etc.

Answer (score 2):

This (injecting a ILogger into a constructor and calling base that needs ILogger) is only possible because `ILogger<T>` is covariant and is just a wrapperclass that has a dependency on the `LoggerFactory`. If it wasn't covariant you would definitely be using the `ILoggerFactory` or `ILogger`. But `ILogger` should be discarded because you could be logging to any category and you would loose all context regarding the logging. I think `ILoggerFactory` would be the best way to go and then use `CreateLogger<T>()` to create a `ILogger<T>` inside you class. This way you really have a nice solution because as a developer you would really like to align the category with your classes to jump right to the code and not to some unrelated derived class. (You could add linesnumbers.) You can also let your derived classes use the logger that is defined by the baseclass but then also where to start looking for the source code? Besides this I can imagine you might also have any other `ILogger` with special purpose category (sub)names in the same class. Nothing is preventing you from have multiple ILogger's in such a case `ILoggerFactory` just looks cleaner.

My preferred solution is to inject `ILoggerFactory` call `CreatLogger<T>` where `T` is the current class and assign it to a `private readonly ILogger<T> logger`

Or in case you already inject `IServiceProvider` you can call `serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<T>>();`

Note that injecting the `IServiceProvider` is the service-locator pattern and is considered an antipattern. Injecting the `ILoggerFactory` is also a variation of the service-locator pattern.

Note: the service provider caches the loggers where the logger factory doesn’t. If using the service provider is undesirable a logger manager can be injected:

```
public interface ILoggerManager
{
    public ILogger<T> CreateLogger<T>();
}

public class LoggerManager : ILoggerManager
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public LoggerManager(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public ILogger<T> CreateLogger<T>()
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<T>>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This added, because a lot of other search results link here.
If you have a `ILoggerFactory` and you need to provide an `ILogger<Whatever>`, this is the way to create it: `new Logger<Whatever>(myLoggerFactory)`

Comment: Yes, but where does `Logger` come from? You'd have to choose a logging library (even if it's MS) in order to have access to that class. If you already have an ILoggerFactory and then use some random Logger class, that logger class has to have a constructor that accepts an ILoggerFactory. This only works if you know or control which log library is in use (or are just lucky). ILoggerFactory has .CreateLogger<T>() which actually uses the ILoggerFactory's Logger implementation class without you having/caring to know what it actually is.

Comment: It comes from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, as described in the original question.

Comment: Or use loggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>(); which does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks. However, `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger` creates an `ILogger` instance, not `ILogger<T>`. If you're in fresh code it probably doesn't matter, but I think I was trying to shim some old code. If there's a way to get the `ILogger<T>` directly from the factory, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this simple technique to inject Ilogger into my legacy classes that require a basic ILogger

```
services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(provider => provider.GetService<ILogger<Startup>>());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my reading the approach in DI "should be" both.

a) When a class is being created, it takes in an `ILogger<T>` *for that class/category*.  It logs all information to that object.

b) If a class also generates new objects itself that require a logger, it should also take in an `ILoggerFactory` and use that to supply loggers to the classes it creates.

That way each object's 'primary log' is directly delivered, but the logs for subordinate classes still receive a log with the all the providers configured etc at the `Host` level.