# Ninject and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, ninject

I'm configuring logging for my .NET Core application (WPF and .NET Core 3). I'd like to leverage `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` through my libraries so there is a common interface and I can easily swap out the logging provider when configuring DI for the application. Reading this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345161/should-i-take-ilogger-iloggert-iloggerfactory-or-iloggerprovider-for-a-libra/51394689#51394689) and this [blog post](https://stackify.com/net-core-loggerfactory-use-correctly/) it appears to be a bad idea to inject either `ILoggerFactory` or `ILogger<T>` into consuming classes. Instead we ought to be injecting `ILogger` but this will require a third-party IOC container to do that for us.

Based on this, and since we're using Ninject, I've configured the Ninject DI as follows:

```
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
kernel.Bind<ILogger>()
   .ToMethod(context =>
       {
         var categoryName = context?.Request?.ParentRequest?.Service.FullName ?? "Unspecified";
         return loggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName);
       });
```

which I think should give me the same behaviour as using `ILogger<T>` but using `ILogger`. Given that I've found this logging stuff somewhat confusing, does the above seem reasonable or am I doing something glaringly wrong?