# ILogger Injection into Class

Tags: azure, .net-core, dependency-injection

What is the difference between `ILogger<T>` and `ILogger`? Below are two ways the `Sample` class using `ILogger`, which one is the best and why!

**Method 1**

```
public class Sample
{
  private readonly ILogger<Sample> _logger;

  public Sample(ILogger<Sample> logger)
  {
    _logger = logger;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("The answer is {number}", 42);
  }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public class Sample
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;

  public Sample(ILogger logger)
  {
    _logger = logger;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("The answer is {number}", 42);
  }
}
```

Comment: This has already been discussed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345161/should-i-take-ilogger-iloggert-iloggerfactory-or-iloggerprovider-for-a-libra

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I take ILogger, ILogger<T>, ILoggerFactory or ILoggerProvider for a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345161/should-i-take-ilogger-iloggert-iloggerfactory-or-iloggerprovider-for-a-libra)

Answer (score 0):

As per usage of ILogger in your .net core which is depends of your requirements.

**ILogger**

`ILogger` is a logger that your code can use to write log messages.

There are three core methods:

`IsEnabled` tests whether a log level is enabled on that logger;

`Log` is the core logging method that is used to write log messages;

`BeginScope` defines a logging scope.

There’s a bunch of logging extension methods that build on that core; the common methods like `LogInformation` are just wrappers around `Log`, with the appropriate arguments.

Internally, an `ILogger` has a “name” (also called a “category”). The idea is that each `ILogger` instance is used by a different component of the application.

`ILogger` is a base interface that provides the core logging functionality, but it is seldom used directly. There are some exceptions (e.g., Azure Functions will pass you an `ILogger`), but most of the time your code will log to an `ILogger<T>`.

**ILogger**

`ILogger<T>` is a logger that is named after a type `T`. All logs sent to an `ILogger<T>` (with the default implementation) will have a logger name/category of `typeof(T).FullName`. `ILogger<T>` is derived from `ILogger` and adds no new functionality.

If you’re using dependency injection, an instance of `ILogger<T>` is usually injected into your type `T`. So, each time you have a constructor that takes an `ILogger<T>`, you are defining a “component” for your application.

**Majar usage of difference**

If you want to log your data as Typed log (serilog, etc., ) you can use `ILogger< T>` or you want to use untyped logs you can simply use ILogger

ASP.NET Core apps, encourage you to use standard `Serilog` interfaces like `Log`, `ILogger`, and `LogContext` if they meet your needs.

Alternatively, your app can consume the ILogger interface from the framework via dependency injection. Serilog implements this interface, so the results are identical for practical purposes.

The `ILoggerFactory` logger factory instance is the boostrapper of the logging system: It is used to attach logger providers and create logger instances - either typed (`ILogger<T>`) or untyped (`ILogger`). These logger instances will log to all registered logger providers.

Refer  [Ilogger best practices](https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/) & [Usage of logging](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2018/06/microsoft-extensions-logging-part-2-types.html)