# why inject ILoggerFactory instead of ILogger<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I read some asp.net core source code and get confused about injecting a Logger, let's take a middleware for example:

```
public class CookiePolicyMiddleware {
   private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
   private readonly ILogger _logger;

   public CookiePolicyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<CookiePolicyOptions> options, ILoggerFactory factory) {
      Options = options.Value;
      _next = next;
      _logger = factory.CreateLogger<CookiePolicyMiddleware>();
   }
   // ...
}
```

so why not we just inject ILogger directly as:

```
public class CookiePolicyMiddleware {
   private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
   private readonly ILogger<CookiePolicyMiddleware> _logger;

   public CookiePolicyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<CookiePolicyOptions> options, ILogger<CookiePolicyMiddleware> logger) {
      Options = options.Value;
      _next = next;
      _logger = logger;
   }
   // ...
}
```

because the default CreateDefaultBuilder method in Program.cs will call `services.AddLogging()` which will registe `ILogger<>` as `Logger<>` (https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,42)

Isn't the second approach more straightforward?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I take ILogger, ILogger<T>, ILoggerFactory or ILoggerProvider for a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345161/should-i-take-ilogger-iloggert-iloggerfactory-or-iloggerprovider-for-a-libra)

Comment: What if you want multiple logger instances or a more descriptive category name. It also depends how it is registered. As a singleton, the injected logger instance will be shared over multiple instances. It might be usefull or not.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure if your example is a copy & paste mistake and if you were meant to inject it a middleware's `.Invoke`.

In constructor injection, they act same and `ILogger<T>` should be preferred unless you are manually instantiating types and want pass a specific logger to it.

Inside `.Invoke`, the case is different, because the middleware runs as singleton.

If you inject `ILogger<T>` in the middle ware constructor, it will create a logger with the log level at the point when it was first created.

If you change the log in `appsettings.json` while the application runs, it won't   use the new values in the middleware logger and still log according to the old settings until the application is restarted.

This is because `Logger<T>` is only a wrapper around `ILoggerFactory.Create` to easily inject an typed logger w/o going over to the factory. The actual logger class is `Logger`. When the logger is created, it gets a copy of the filter options (see [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggerFactory.cs#L76)).

So the changes in filter settings will only be applied on newly created loggers.

What happens in the code above is, that the factory is injected and the logger created in the `Invoke` method, which creates a new logger on every request, thus also loading the most recent filter and settings from `appsettings.json` and allows live changing of log level without restarting of the application.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, really helped me a lot.

Comment: just a small question,  https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy/CookiePolicyMiddleware.cs,27 you can see that this middlware doesn't call CreateLogger in Invoke method, still create a logger in the constructor

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, since most applications do not expect the log filters to change while the application runs. If one has a specific requirement that log levels must be able to be changed without restarting the application, this scenario won't work

Comment: thanks for your comment. So in that case, why CookiePolicyMiddleware doesn't inject `ILogger<CookiePolicyMiddleware>` directly into its constructor if there is no requirement that log levels must be able to be changed without restarting the application?