# Need Clarification : Logging data in to Application Insights from Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I an trying to log details of my function app into Application Insights.

My basic code:

```
    public class AzureAppInsightsExplore
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AzureAppInsightsExplore> logger;
        public AzureAppInsightsExplore(ILogger<AzureAppInsightsExplore> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
        [FunctionName("AzureAppInsightsExplore")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log) //Can we directly use log
        {
            // Unable to find this log in trace but in live metrics it is shown.
            logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            int a = 0, b = 0;
            //Unhandled exception
            int c = a / b;
            return new OkObjectResult(string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Host.Json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedTypes": "Request"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Here are few strange things I have noticed (not sure where I am doing wrong).

1. Unhandled Exception is logging twice in Application Insights.
   [image]
2. Any specific reason to inject `ILogger<ClassName> logger` when function run method is having `ILogger log` by default.
3. Main concern is that I am seeing a lot of unwanted logs in trace table, where I am just expecting it would have information that I log in code with `log.LogXXX(message)`.
   Is there a way that I can stop loading unwanted data `Trace` table, because it would increase the cost.
   [image]
4. I am not see those logs messages that I am logging from code (I have tried after 10 mins, as it might take some time to load into trace tables) , but I can see those logs in Live metrics.

[image]

Can someone suggest me on the above, It would be really helpful.

Kind regards.

Comment: Have you seen this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hooman Bahreini, According to [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51394689) it says,

> **ILogger**: is responsible to write a log message of a given  *Log Level*.
> **ILoggerProvider**: is responsible to create an instance of  `ILogger`  (you are not supposed to use  `ILoggerProvider`  directly to create a logger).
> **ILoggerFactory**: you can register one or more  `ILoggerProvider`s with the factory, which in turn uses all of them to create an instance of  `ILogger`.  `ILoggerFactory`  holds a collection of  `ILoggerProviders`.

We can able to see logging messages you need give correct format in quotations and column name too:
[image]