# How to access ILogger in all classes in Azure Function running on .NET Core 6 isolated

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, ilogger, azure-functions-isolated

I'm converting a web job to an Azure Function. I created an Azure Function with .NET 6 isolated. I'm unable to access the ILogger from class constructor, getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory' while attempting to
> activate 'ABC'

Here is my code:

```
namespace MyFunction
{
    public class MyFunctionProcessor
    {
        private readonly ILogger log;
        private IABC _iABC;

        public MyFunctionProcessor(ILoggerFactory logger, IABC _iABC)
        {
            log = logger.CreateLogger<MyFunctionProcessor>();
            this._iABC = _iABC;
        }

        [Function(nameof(MyFunctionProcessor))]
        public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%", 
            Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] EventData[] events, PartitionContext partitionContext)
        {
            Guid correlationId = Guid.NewGuid();
            log.LogInformation($"CorrelationId: {correlationId} ABC Processor Function has been started");

            try
            {
                await this._iABC.SyncDataAsync(events, partitionContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"CorrelationId: {correlationId} Exception while processing the event {ex.Message} => {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ABC class file:

```
namespace MyFunction.Services
{
    public class ABC : IABC
    {
         private IService serv;
         private ILogger log;

         public ABC(IService _serv, LoggerFactory _log)
         {
              serv = _serv;
              log =_log.CreateLogger<ABC>();
         }
         
          public async Task SyncDataAsync(EventData[] messages, PartitionContext context)
          {
              // code logic
              var xyz = serv.getDetails();          
              // code logic
          }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs` file:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    services.AddScoped<IABC, ABC>();
    services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();
    services.AddLogging();
    services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
})
.Build();

host.Run();
```

Class library service code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Service : IService
    {
         private ILogger log;

         public Service(LoggerFactory _log)
         {
              log =_log.CreateLogger<Service>();
         }
         
         public async Task getDetails()
         {
             // code logic
             // here I'm logging the details
         }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to use IFunctionHostBuilder inside a Startup.cs file. You'll get that interface when you inherit from FunctionsStartup.

Comment: @GHDevOps, In Isolated azure function there will not be a startup class right ? only program.cs class will be there  as per my understanding . if my perspective is wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

An `ILoggerFactory` was registered for dependency injection (DI).  But `ABC`'s constructor

```
public ABC(IService _serv, LoggerFactory _log)
{
     serv = _serv;
     log =_log.CreateLogger<ABC>();
}
```

requires a `LoggerFactory`.  That constructor parameter type would need to be changed to `ILoggerFactory`.

However, the use of `ILoggerFactory` isn't required.  An `ILogger<T>` will be available for DI, so the use of the factory within the constructor can be avoided.  For example, `ABC`'s constructor could be changed to:

```
private readonly ILogger<ABC> _logger;
public ABC(IService _serv, ILogger<ABC> logger)
{
     serv = _serv;
     _logger = logger;
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345161/should-i-take-ilogger-iloggert-iloggerfactory-or-iloggerprovider-for-a-libra) might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for answer. however it didn't worked for me. Could you please suggest me how to add Ilogger  dependency in program.cs file .

Comment: Remove `services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory...` and `services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>)...`.  The call to `services.AddLogging();` should configure `LoggerFactory` to provide an `ILogger<T>` (not ILogger) where needed.