# C# Ilogger<T> or IloggerFactory

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I have the the following scenario. The BaseParser is an abstract class with some basic functionality. Same are the Fileparser and DbParser and both extend the BaseParser. The rest are concrete implementations of either File/Db parser. This is a visual representation:

[image]

**Problem**
The factory initializes all parsers. In the factory by DI the `ILogger<Factory>` is injected and initialized, however that's not the case with the parsers. Each of them have in the constructor an `ILogger` parameter with a type depending on their class ex: `ILogger<FileParser>` or `Ilogger<Parser1>` etc and they must be injected from the Factory.

**Question**
And here comes the problem. How can I pass from the factory the Logger instance to suit each class with a categorized log instance all the way down to the BaseParser. Is this even achievable? I thought about injecting IloggerFactory in the parsers instead of Ilogger and then assign the right category to each logging instance in the construcor of the parser like in the example below, is this seen as a bad practice?

```
private readonly ILoggerFactory _logger;

public ParserX(IloggerFactory loggerFactory){
   _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("ParserX")
}
```

P.S Might be a dublicate of this article [Should I take ILogger, ILogger<T>, ILoggerFactory or ILoggerProvider for a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345161/should-i-take-ilogger-iloggert-iloggerfactory-or-iloggerprovider-for-a-libra?rq=2)

But it still didn't answer my question..

Comment: As you mentioned, injecting `IloggerFactory` might be an option  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#log-category

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk the only problem with this approach is in the unit testing part. I instantiante the Factory and it expects an instance of IloggerFactory, since this is an interface what shall I pass to the constructor of the factory?

Comment: You can simply pass `NullLoggerFactory.Instance`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.nullloggerfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: I mean, when you initialize your class, you can simply use `NullLoggerFactory.Instance` which is a dummy implementation of the `IloggerFactory `

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk ok thanks, this is what I was looking for, should do the job for unit testing